# How to show dynamic columns as per hierarchy using a slicer?

Tags: powerbi, dax, hierarchy

For example, I have 4 levels of hierarchy which go into a slicer (L1, L2, L3, L4),
now if i select L1, I should get values of the hierarchy bellow L1 i.e. the values of L2 and if L2 is selected show the values of L3 and so on.
Please help!

I am not able to figure out what to do exactly.

Answer (score 0):

That is the usual behavior of the slicer. You are picking the highest level of hierarchy. All of the values inside that level are selected automatically as well then...

Comment: But I don't wanna see the highest value of the hierarchy that i select.

Comment: Sorry, could you please somehow visualize your request? I do not really understand

Comment: Like in the above example, if L1 is the highest hierarchy, L2 is under it and the L3 under L2.
So if we select L1, I should get the values of only L2 in the visual not L1 and similarly if I select L2 , I should get the values of the hierarchy under it i.e. L3 only and if I select L3 I should get the value of L3 only as there is nothing under it in the hierarchy.